# How do you determine rendered text width so it can be centered in pygame?

Tags: python-3.x, fonts, pygame

I am creating my first Pygame board game. I want to display the game title in the sidebar to the right of the game board. I've computed the width of the sidebar, but now I haven't found a method to report how wide the rendered text is so I can subtract half the width from the center-line.

Is there a function for this? I've searched several other sites, but haven't found the right answer yet.

Answer (score 1):

For displaying text in pygame:

- Use **pygame.font.SysFont** to set the font name and size
- Use **Sysfont.render** to create surface object of the text
- Use **Rect.center** to set the center of the text surface
- Use **Surface.blit** to draw the text surface onto the main screen surface

Here's some sample code:

```
import pygame 
pygame.init()

win = pygame.display.set_mode((300,100))
pygame.display.set_caption("Text")

font = pygame.font.SysFont("impact", 40)  # font name and size
text = font.render("<< Python >>", False, (100,255,100)) # surface for text
textRect = text.get_rect()
textRect.center = (300//2, 100//2)  # center of text is screen center
win.blit(text, textRect) # draw text
pygame.display.update()

while True:
    pygame.time.delay(100)
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.quit(); exit()
```

Output

[image: Text]